# How to fix this code to have a working live clock and a stopwatch on the side? It is a small planning program

Tags: c

Unfortunately the clock in the beginning does not work and also the program does not calculate the time spent on work while I want it to be a topwatch constantly going on on the side. How can I do it? I dont know what to do.

Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void displayTime(int h, int m, int s)
{
    printf("Clock: %02d:%02d:%0.2d\n", h, m, s);
}

void displayTasks(char tasks[][50], int timeSpent[], int taskCount, int workingTask)
{
    printf("\nTask List:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < taskCount; i++)
        {
            printf("%d. %s\tTime Spent: %d seconds\n", i + 1, tasks[i], timeSpent[i]);
        }

    if(workingTask != -1)
    {
        printf("\nWorking on: %s\n", tasks[workingTask]); 
    }
}

int main()
{
    int h = 0;
    int m = 0;
    int s = 0;
    int d = 1;

    char tasks[100][50];
    int taskCount = 0;
    int timeSpent[100] = {0};
    int workingTask = -1;
    int clockStarted = 0;

    printf("Set time (HH MM SS): ");
    scanf("%d%d%d", &h, &m, &s);

    if(h > 12 || m >= 60 || s >= 60)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Invalid time\n");
        return(1);
    }

    while(1)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            printf("\n");
        }

        if(clockStarted)
        {
            displayTime(h, m, s);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Clock: not started\n");
        }

        displayTasks(tasks, timeSpent, taskCount, workingTask);

        printf("\n1. Add Task\n");
        printf("2. Start Working on Task\n");
        printf("3. Complete Working Task\n");
        printf("4. Start Clock\n");
        printf("5. Exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice: ");

        int choice;
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        if(choice == 1)
        {
            printf("Enter task description: ");
            scanf(" %[^\n]s", tasks[taskCount]);
            taskCount++;
        } 
   
        else if (choice == 2) 
        {
            if (taskCount > 0)
            {
                printf("Enter the task number to start working on: ");
                scanf("%d", &workingTask);
                workingTask--; // Convert to array index
            }
            else 
            {
                printf("No tasks available to start working on.\n");
            }
        }

        else if (choice == 3)
        {
            if (workingTask != -1)
            {
                timeSpent[workingTask]++;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("No task currently being worked on.\n");
            }
        }
        else if (choice == 4)
        {
            clockStarted = 1;
        }
        else if (choice == 5)
        {
            printf("\nEnd of the day summary:\n");
            displayTasks(tasks, timeSpent, taskCount, -1);
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Invalid choice. Please enter a valid option.\n");
        }

        sleep(d);

        if (clockStarted)
        {
            s++;
            if (s >= 60)
            {
                m++;
                s = 0;
            }
            if (m >= 60)
            {
                h++;
                m = 0;
            }
            if (h > 12)
            {
                h = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to fix it countless times, didnt happen.

Comment: I would definitely recommend trying to step through your program in a debugger - it should help you understand a lot more. For example, if you trace around your loop you will realise that the clock can only tick over one second every time you make a choice from the menu, because your scanf() is called every loop and it blocks the remaining code.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with the code is that it's updating time based on how many times the user interacts with the program in the while loop, which means the time will only update when a loop has executed. (@nick-gris might have explained it in a better way in his comment)

The approach you have to do is to depend on the current time instead. You can use C function [time](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time), which will return total seconds.

So, you'll have to take the total seconds first, and do your conversion for hours and minutes (simple division). And when the user interacts with the program, you should take the time again, but subtract it from the previous time. This will make the program calculate how much time was spent.

Take a look at this example:

```c
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    time_t t, temp;
    t = time(NULL); // Current time in seconds.
    temp = t; // Temporary time holder that will be used later. // Seconds
    int choice, s, m, h; // Hours, minutes, and choice of user.
    printf("Welcome! The stopwatch has started.\n");
    
    while(1){
        printf("Enter your choice\n[1] check time.\n[2]exit\n\n>>> ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        if (choice == 1){
            temp = time(NULL); // Taking the time again. The number of seconds will be increased when the user presses 1.
            h = (temp - t)/3600; 
            m = (temp - t)/60 - h*60; 
            s = (temp - t) - m*60 - h*3600; 
            printf("Total elapsed: %d hours, %d minutes, and %d seconds\n", h, m, s);
        } else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

This will start like a stopwatch. Each time the user presses 1, it'll display how much time was elapsed since the start of the stopwatch. You can apply similar approach in your program.

I decided not to modify your code so you could understand the approach properly and implement it yourself.

And for C folks, please correct me if I did anything wrong here, I'm not a C expert.

Answer (score 1):

each `while()` iteration you do this:

```
int choice;
scanf("%d", &choice);
```

That means every single iteration you have to insert a choice before the program continues (aka you will not get to the timing section unless someone type his choice).

Using `switch` instruction (instead of many `if else` statements) and `enum` for the choices might be really helpful in readability of your code and it isn't hard to implement.